# Regasm can't find embedded assemblies

Tags: .net, com-interop, regasm

I'm developing a .Net component that will live inside Windows application as a plugin.  This plugin will be registered on the client machine using regasm.  My component embeds most of its dependencies and returns assemblies to the AppDomain when they're requested.  If I try to run regasm on my single dll, it fails because it can't locate the dependencies within the folder.  This will be a problem when installing the component on the client machines.

Is there a way to tell regasm where to get the embedded dlls?

What I've tried so far:

1. Register the component with the dlls nearby then copy the single dll to the runtime folder. My component works and the dlls are discovered at runtime, but this is not an option for deployment.
2. Hook in using ComRegisterFunctionAttribute.  This only gets called if the dlls are nearby so it's not any better than #1.

I don't have any control over the fact that regasm will get called.  I don't *have* to make my component a single dll, but it would make deployment considerably easier provided I can solve this problem.

Comment: have you tried `regasm /codebase` ?  That puts the path to your assembly file in the COM registration entries (in the registry).

Comment: I have no control over how regasm gets called unfortunately, however regasm has no trouble finding my assembly.  It just can't find the assemblies embedded in it -- and doesn't ask it where they are.

Comment: Who is calling regasm?  an MSI installer?

Comment: The app.  It does some checking to see if there are components to add.  It pulls them down and registers them before trying to load them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer:**

I am guessing that your `[ComRegisterFunction]` is over a method in a class that references types from one of the other assemblies.  Your code is probably not run because it can't JIT-compile the ComRegister method because it can't find the assembly for one of the types in your class or method.

Try creating a class that has no external dependencies (other than the .net framework), and putting the ComRegisterFunction attribute in that class. Do your install work there, but only dynamically load assemblies from other types so you can use custom code to locate the external assemblies.

Comment: Yes, that's how my dll finds its embedded assemblies.  This works quite well.  Regasm is the one that can't find them.  I think my solution will be to remove references to the embedded dlls and load the main one via reflection using the name.

Comment: Since you edited your answer, my comment looks out of place, but you now seem to have a better handle on the problem.  Your answer there is what I ended up doing: 

I removed the references in the COM registered dll.  It loads the startup stuff from a dependency dll via reflection.  This hack works very well.

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score -1):

Ld00d, I had the same problem. How did you do this: "I removed the references in the COM registered dll"? It sounds like magic to me. Did you use ildasm and then ilasm?

I think there is no solution for this serious problem of regasm.exe.

regasm.exe invokes `[ComRegisterFunction]` method only if the previuos verification of assembly `GetReferencedAssemblies` ends with success. 
You may try to ildasm and then ilasm your dll to remove these references, but I think it could bring chaos. I also do not know what would happen if you ofuscate the code.

My workaround:

1. During installation copy those DLLs asked by regasm.exe into the folder of your DLL.
2. Remove them just after regasm.exe finishes registeration of your DLL.

Not nice (the installer software eats a lot of disk space), but works.